# How can the state of an Entity be Added but call to CallTracker.HasChanges() return false?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0, c#-9.0

I am using EF Core 5.0.

I have a class called JobApplicationManager that OwnsMany() of JobApplications.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<JobApplicationManager>().OwnsMany(s => s.JobApplicationCategories, a =>
       {
           a.Property<DateTime>("CreatedDate");
           a.Property<DateTime>("UpdatedDate");
           a.ToTable("JobApplicationManagerCategories");
       });

        modelBuilder.Entity<JobApplication>().OwnsMany(s => s.JobApplicationCategories, a =>
        {
            a.Property<DateTime>("CreatedDate");
            a.Property<DateTime>("UpdatedDate");
            a.ToTable("JobApplicationCategories");
        });
```

Current state: There is one JobApplicationManager in the DB with one JobApplication.
Action: I add another JobApplication to the JobApplicationManager.

In my DBContext.SaveChangesAsync() I call ChangeTracker.Entries() and the following is the entities:
[image]

As you can see the first entry is the JobApplication with status of Added.
[image]

Also in this DBContect you can see the JobApplicationManager has two JobApplications:

[image]

The next step I can ChangeTracker.HasChanges() which returns false so therefor base.SaveChangesAsync() returns 0 number of entities written.

I dont know what to do.

Here is the code that creates my entity and calls my repository:

```
        var mgr = await AMRepository.GetJobApplicationManagerAsync(command.JobApplicationManagerID);
       var newJobApplication = mgr.AddJobApplication(command.JobDescriptionURL, command.JobTitle, command.FileName, command.CompanyName, command.GeographicLocation, command.RecruiterName, command.JobApplicationCategories);

        // Update the Repository
        AMRepository.Update(mgr);

        commandResult = await AMRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveEntitiesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Here is the code in my Repository:

```
        public void Update(JobApplicationManager applicationManager)
    {
        try
        {
            AppManagerContext.Entry(applicationManager).State = EntityState.Modified;

    }
```

Here is the code in my DBContext for SaveEntitiesAsync():

```
public async Task<bool> SaveEntitiesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var changesFlag1 = ChangeTracker.HasChanges();

            // Dont save the enumeration Value Object types
            try
            {               
                var enumerationEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                        .Where(x => EnumerationTypes.Contains(x.Entity.GetType()));

                foreach (var enumerationEntry in enumerationEntries)
                {
                    enumerationEntry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
            }

            UpdateShadowProperties();

            var numberOfStateEntitiesWritten = 0;
            try
            {
                numberOfStateEntitiesWritten = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
            }

            if (numberOfStateEntitiesWritten == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Here is the code from the Repository for GetJobApplicationManagersAsync():

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<JobApplicationManager>> GetJobApplicationManagersAsync() => await AppManagerContext.JobApplicationManagers.ToListAsync();
```

Within mgr.AddApplication() all I do is add POCO classes to the mgr.  There is no infrastructure related activities (i.e. using DBContext)>

Comment: Post the code that adds a new entity and calls `SaveChangesAsync`. These screenshots don't show any problem or explain what you tried. How is `ChangeTracker.HasChanges()` involved at all? And why is *base*.SaveChangesAsync() used? Have you tried to override `SaveChangesAsync`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I posted the code you requested.

Comment: We don't see what happens in `GetJobApplicationManagerAsync` and `mgr.AddJobApplication`. In general, there's too much manual state management in your code. Let EF track objects without interfering. For example, make sure these "EnumerationType"s never get state added or modified in the first place. Also, don't expect setting state to `Modified` to "notice" changed navigation properties. And *why* do you have to set `mgr` to modified? Looks like there are just too many layers involved by which you shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @GertArnold I added the code for GetJobApplicationManagerAsync() and explained AddJobApplication().  The enumeration types I ensure the state are UnChanged.  The other questions I dont see how they are relevant to the question of not storing the new JobApplication.  I showed the state of everything right before DBContext.SaveChangesAsync() is called.

Comment: If you don't give a [mcve] it is very hard to help you.